# PHP intellisense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Does anybody know how to get mysqli functions to show up in the PHP intellisense in VS Code?

I got PHP intellisense extension installed, PHP path setup, it works for basic functions but not for mysqli. I got it working by setting:

```
"php.suggest.basic": false
```

However, this disables the basic commands for PHP such as include etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try this extension? Might solve your problem https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bschulte.php-autocomplete